# Unwanted redirection on first request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem in my MVC project were the first time I request a page it makes a redirection to another area, but the second time I request it works correctly.
The url I use is: http://localhost:2012/pt/Documentation/Index and redirects me to http://localhost:2012/es/Services/Documentation

I've debugged the code and in both requests the url asked for is the first, and the action that respond the request is correct, but once the reply gets to the browser , the first time is recieved with a 302 code and it redirects me to this second URL.
I've checked the web.config with any redirection rule but there aren't.

The Area registration is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { language = "es", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And the controller is like:

```
public class DocumentationController : Controller
{   
    public ActionResult Index(string language)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The setCulture is an atribute that is used to change the translations needed in the view.
I've tried to comment the view and the layout but it still redirects without code.
Any help will be aprecciated.

****EDIT****

First request:
[image: First request]

Second request:
[image: Second request]
The view code is:

```
@model string
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Resend documentation";
    Layout = null;
}
```

Comment: Nothing in the code you've shared will do a 302. So there must be something else performing the redirect

Comment: Yeah, I know it's hard to believe but this only happens on this controller, I've changed the name of it but with the new name still have the redirection the first time.

Comment: It's not hard to believe TBH, there are lots of points in MVC where a redirect could be triggered. You just haven't found where yet. Check the `global.asax` is one place. No one here can help